# How can I convert an already created sidebar into a responsive design?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

The sidebar looks like the below snippet. What should i add to this code, like a wrapper to make it responsive in mobile screen?

```css
.sidebar{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    width: 314px;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #002438;
    box-shadow: hsl(0, 0%, 75%) 7px 2px 15px;
}

.sidebar li{
    margin-top: 45px;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.sidebar a{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.sidebar li :hover{
    color: #00fff2;
     
}
.sidelist{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}
.active a{
    width: 230px !important;
    display: block;
    margin: 10px auto;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background: #fff;    
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
      <ul class="sidelist">
          <li><a href="index.html">DASHBOARD</a></li>
          <li class="active"><a href="#" style="color:  #002438; font-weight: bolder;">CUSTOMER</a></li>
          <li><a href="leads.html">LEADS</a></li>
          <li><a href="reports.html">REPORTS</a></li>
          <li><a href="sms.html">SMS</a></li>
          <li><a href="profile.html">PROFILE</a></li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

This is my sidebar. How do i turn it into a hamburger icon in mobile screens, which when clicked or dragged, moved from left to right side with all the sidebar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I might do is use a media query. If you want this to just be an icon button with the little hamburger icon, make the icon button above or below where you made this sidebar. In your css that you have there, give it another class maybe something like this:

```
.menuIcon {
  display: 'none';
  /* your other styles here */
}
```

Then the media query (you can make more than one) do something like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .menuIcon {
    /* styles */
  }
  .sidebar {
    display: 'none';
    /* styles */
  }
}
```

Of course change the media query to match what size screen you want to adjust for, and style how you want.